# Redundant tags [last], [next]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I noticed this [last](/questions/tagged/last) tag today while browsing. It doesn't seem to have any merit on its own, and every question tagged with it also looks to be tagged with whatever the questioner is interested in the 'last' *of*.

There are currently 273 questions tagged with it, so it seems a bit too large to do by hand. Can we burninate it?

Edit: on a hunch, also checked [next](/questions/tagged/next), which has +450 questions and is equally as useless.

Comment: I'm on the case.